# Unable to start Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Unable to start Visual Studio 2010.

Error

**The type name could not be resolved Parameter name: windowtype**

Screenshot

[image]

The only solution I had in mind is to re-install Visual Studio or Windows.

Is there any other way to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN, this issue is resolved. Here is the link

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572085/isolated-shell-2010-unable-to-call-com-component-in-exe-before-start

I think downloading and applying the latest service pack and hot fixes (you can get using Windows Update), will do the trick.